# Finding the Fourier series of a piecewise-defined function $f:[-\pi,\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

$$  f(x)= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      x^2 &  -\pi\leq x < -\frac{\pi}{2} \\
      \sin(x) & -\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x< 0 \\
      x-\pi & 0\leq x < \frac{\pi}{2} \\
      e^x & \frac{\pi}{2}\leq x < \pi \\
\end{array} 
\right. $$

Basically what I'm trying to do is find the Fourier coefficients like this:
$$ \begin{align*}
a_0&=\frac{1}{2\ell}\int_{-\ell}^\ell f(x)dx \\
a_k&=\frac{1}{\ell}\int_{-\ell}^\ell f(x)\cos(\frac{k\pi x}{\ell})dx \\
b_k&=\frac{1}{\ell}\int_{-\ell}^{\ell} f(x)\sin(\frac{k\pi x}{\ell})dx
\end{align*}$$
with $\ell=\pi$. Am I correct to assume that I can get the coefficient by integrating like this?
$$
a_k=\frac{1}{\pi}\left[\int_{-\pi}^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}x^2\cos(kx)dx+\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^0\sin(x)\cos(kx)dx+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(x-\pi)\cos(kx)dx+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^\pi e^x\cos(kx)\right]
$$

And if so, how can I simplify, because right now I'm getting  something very convoluted like this:
$$
a_k=\frac{ \left( 8-\pi^2k^2 \right) \sin \left( \frac{k\pi}{2} \right) -4k\pi\cos \left( \frac{k\pi}{2} \right) +8k\pi\cos \left( k\pi \right) }{4\pi k^3}+\frac{1}{\pi \left( k^2-1 \right) }+ \left( -\frac{1}{2k}\sin \left( \frac{k\pi}{2} \right) +\frac{1}{k^2\pi}\cos \left( \frac{k\pi}{2} \right) -\frac{1}{k^2\pi} \right) +\frac{e^{\pi}k\sin \left( k\pi \right) -e^{\frac{\pi}{2}}k\sin \left( \frac{k\pi}{2} \right) +e^{\frac{\pi}{2}}k\cos \left( \frac{k\pi}{2} \right) -e^{\pi}k\cos \left( k\pi \right) }{k^2+1}
$$

Am I doing something wrong? I haven't even bothered with $b_k$ because i feel like I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: You might try finding the coefficients using their [exponential form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Exponential_form), then deduce $a_k$ and $b_k$. Integrating $\sin x \cos \frac{k\pi x}\ell$ by exploiting trig identities is a bit more cumbersome than integrating $\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\cdot\frac{e^{i k \pi x/\ell}+e^{-i k \pi x/\ell}}2$

Comment: Who assigned this problem? I can't see what pedagogical benefit there is in this exercise over just computing the FT of a sawtooth wave. Maybe the thinking is that it's harder for students to cheat?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to split up the integral like that, and you should expect a messy answer owing to the fact that you have a piecewise-defined function.

Some simplifications can be made to the trig functions in your answer. A list I have in a personal document is as follows: for any integer $\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\pf}[2]{\left( \frac{#1}{#2} \right)}
\newcommand{\case}[1]{\begin{cases} #1 \end{cases}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\left \lfloor #1 \right \rfloor}
\newcommand{\para}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
\newcommand{\al}[1]{\begin{align*} #1 \end{align*}}
n$,

$$\al{
\sin(n \pi) &= 0\\
\cos(n \pi) &= (-1)^n\\
\sin \pf{n\pi}{2} &= \case{ 
1, & n = 4k+1 \text{ for a } k \in \Z \\
-1, & n = 4k+3 \text{ for a } k \in \Z \\
0, & \text{otherwise}} \\
&= \frac{(-1)^{(n-1)/2} \Big( 1 - (-1)^n \Big)}{2} \\
&= \frac{(-1)^{\floor{(n-1)/2}} + (-1)^{\floor{n/2}}}{2} \\
\cos \pf{n\pi}{2} &= \case{ 
1, & n = 4k \text{ for a } k \in \Z \\
-1, & n = 4k+2 \text{ for a } k \in \Z \\
0, & \text{otherwise}} \\
&= \frac{(-1)^{n/2} \Big( 1 - (-1)^{n-1} \Big)}{2}\\
&= \frac{(-1)^{\floor{n/2}} + (-1)^{\floor{(n+1)/2}}}{2}\\
 \sin \para{ \frac{2n+1}{2} \pi } &= (-1)^n\\
\cos \para{ \frac{2n+1}{2} \pi } &= 0
}
$$